# submit button never post data after doing 1 function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have login form here,

```
   <form action="proseslogin.php" method="POST">
       <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="username">
       <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="password">
       <button class="btn btn-info btn-block login" type="submit">Login</button>
   </form>
```

js code

```
$(function(){
    var textfield = $("input[name=username]");
    $('button[type="submit"]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //little validation just to check username
        if (textfield.val() != "") {
            //$("body").scrollTo("#output");
            $("#output").addClass("alert alert-success animated fadeInUp").html("Welcome back " + "<span style='text-transform:uppercase'>" + textfield.val() + "</span>");
            $("#output").removeClass(' alert-danger');
            $("input").css({
                "height":"0",
                "padding":"0",
                "margin":"0",
                "opacity":"0"
            });
            //change button text 
            $('button[type="submit"]').html("continue")
                                      .removeClass("btn-info")
                                      .addClass("btn-default")
                    .click(function(){
                        $("input").css({
                            "height":"auto",
                            "padding":"10px",
                            "opacity":"1"
                        }).val("");
                    });

            //show avatar
            $(".avatar").css({
                "background-image": "url(assets/img/clublogo.png)"
            });
        } else {
            //remove success mesage replaced with error message
            $("#output").removeClass(' alert alert-success');
            $("#output").addClass("alert alert-danger animated fadeInUp").html("sorry enter a username ");
         }
         //console.log(textfield.val());
    });
});
```

form is okay and work, but when I add some function in javascript to make good-looking-form, the button never executing the action and posting the data instead do loop-change-text-button function

Comment: Because e.preventDefault(); will prevent the form submission

Comment: use `return false` wherever you needed based on your conditions to prevent `form` submit remove `e.preventDefault();` it preventing button's behavior please read [event.preventDefault](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Comment: thx for the explanation, I will try modification the code to use prevent default but still can login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you code should execute only when button.html == 'Login' . Just add addition if to check it.

```
if ($(this).html() == 'Login') {
```

after

```
$('button[type="submit"]').click(function(e) {
     if ($(this).html() == 'Login') {
     // all you code here
     }
});
```

Comment: the js function do a change text 'submit' to 'continue' in button (I still need this function tho), but when I try to add your code, when I click submit, form straight to execute the action without need click continue once more

Comment: thx, even it still go straight execute the action, but I understand what you mean at that code I'll try repair myself